# SSRS report suddenly not pulling back data

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

We have an SSRS report that has suddenly stopped pulling back any data.  It was working fine last week, but today it pulls back nothing.  The only thing that has changed is we upgraded to Oracle version 19c.

Is there any known issues with Oracle 19c and SSRS?

I can connect to the data sources in the report successfully, but it just won't pull back data when I run the report.

Comment: Does the code with parameters return data as expected?

Comment: I would try running the report out of Visual Studio to see if there's an error message that isn't coming through the report server. Then try running the query in the dataset's Query Designer.